# keras:expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions

Tags: python, keras

```python
from keras import optimizers
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
# dimensions of our images
img_width, img_height = 313, 220

# load the model we saved
model = load_model('hmodel.h5')
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy','mse'])

test_image= image.load_img('/Images/1.jpg',target_size = (img_width, img_height))
x= scipy.misc.imread('/Images/1.jpg').shape
print x
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height,3)
result = model.predict(test_image)

print result
```

When I run this code i get this error:

> /keras/engine/training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
>       'with shape ' + str(data_shape)) ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape
>   (313, 220, 3).

My first `print` displays: `(313, 220, 3)`.

How can I fix this error.

Comment: What is the input shape of your model? Adding more information, like the model definition, woud probably help in answering your question.

Comment: If you don't have the model code, can you show the output of `model.summary()`

Comment: model.add(Dense(150,kernel_initializer='normal', input_dim=36, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(36,kernel_initializer='uniform',activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='sigmoid'))

Answer (score 0):

Your first layer `Dense(150,kernel_initializer='normal', input_dim=36, activation='relu')` expects an input with 2 dimensions: `(*, 36)` (with the first dimension corresponding to your batch size).

However your input `x` has actually 3 dimensions - 4 dimensions once properly batched:`(*, 313, 220, 3)`.

If you want a `Dense` layer accepting such an input, you could use the parameter `input_shape=(313, 220, 3)` instead of `input_dim=36`.

---

Remark:
You are not *batching* your image correctly.

```python
test_image= image.load_img('/Images/1.jpg',target_size = (img_width, img_height))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)       # shape = (313, 220, 3)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0) # shape = (1, 313, 220, 3)
# Remove this line below, as it would set back shape to (313, 220, 3)
# test_image = test_image.reshape(img_width, img_height,3)
result = model.predict(test_image)
```

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 313, 220, 3)

Comment: Have you applied the first part of my answer, i.e. redefining your first `Dense` layer with `input_shape=(313, 220, 3)` instead of `input_dim=36` as parameter? (`model.add(Dense(150,kernel_initializer='normal', input_shape=(313, 220, 3), activation='relu')) `)

Comment: sorry i couldn't do that because:1- i'll not have just one images, i have to predict too many images(different size).2-my model is defined by GridSearchCV

Comment: If the images all have the same shape (e.g. `(313, 220, 3)`) or if you can resize them before, this code will work. Otherwise, things get more complicated (see this discussion for instance: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-convnet-for-variable-size-input-dimension-images/1906/3).